Issue using matplotlib.pyplot in pycharm console for Matplotlib 3.9.0
Hi I am finding an issue with pycharm console (PyCharm 2023.2.7 community edition) when I set up a new venv and install matplotlib (3.9.0), I find that I am unable to plot a figure.
When I type the following:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()

The figure window opens but then stays in a minimized form that cannot be expanded (windows spinning circle when mouse hovers over window). This window cannot be minimized without crashing python.  However I can plt.close() the window from the console.  This does not affect matplotlib when imported  and called in a .py script
I have figured that downgrading matplotlib to <3.9.0 could recover figures in the pycharm console however I wondered if there is something that I am missing in pycharm when using matplotlib 3.9.0 or if this should be raised with pycharm?
Thanks for any pointers

It seems like this is due to a compatibility issue between PyCharm and the renewed BackendRegistry in Matplotlib 3.9, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/28449#issuecomment-2191203048.
PyCharm apparently uses the backend "tkagg" by default and somehow relies on matplotlib storing it as "TkAgg" in rcParams. However, since Matplotlib 3.9, that value is stored with whatever case provided.
It's reported to PyCharm with https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-73139.
The work-around is to select the backend yourself as "TkAgg":
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()

